# Current from Internal Energy?

Tags: thermoelectricity

Internal energy in a conductor includes the collective vibration of the constituent particles including electrons and nuclei.

If I place a heated conductor in a magnetic field, the charges will experience some sort of confining force such that the individual electrons will gyrate around the magnetic field lines. Due to their random thermal kinetic energy, do they drift off along the magnetic field producing a current, or is there a flaw in my reasoning?

How efficient would this internal energy (kinetic energy) to electric potential energy conversion process be?

Comment: You're missing some things. Take a look at the Lorentz force, the with an average velocity of $\vec 0$. The magnetic field won't do anything unless you also apply an electric field with it.